# Insert data in MongoDB using mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm trying to insert some data in MongoDB using mgo but the outcome is not what I wanted.

**My struct**

```
    type Slow struct {
    Endpoint string
    Time     string
    }
```

**My insert statement**

```
err := collection.Insert(&Slow{endpoint, e}) 
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

**How I'm trying to print it**

```
    var results []Slow

    err := collection.Find(nil).All(&results)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }   
    s, _ := json.MarshalIndent(results, "  ", "  ")
    w.Write(s)
```

**My output (Marshaled JSON)**

```
   [{
       "Endpoint": "/api/endpoint1",
       "Time": "0.8s"
    },
    {
       "Endpoint": "/api/endpoint2",
       "Time": "0.7s"
    }]
```

**What I wanted**

```
    {
      "/api/endpoint1":"0.8s",
      "/api/endpoint2":"0.7s"
    }
    //No brackets
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you seem to want the results sorted by `Endpoint`. If you don't specify any sort order when querying, you can have no guarantee of any specific order. So query them like this:

```
err := collection.Find(nil).Sort("endpoint").All(&results)
```

Next, what you want is not the JSON representation of the results. To get the format you want, use the following loop:

```
w.Write([]byte{'{'})
for i, slow := range results {
    if i > 0 {
        w.Write([]byte{','})
    }
    w.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("\n\t\"%s\":\"%v\"", slow.Endpoint, slow.Time)))
}
w.Write([]byte("\n}"))
```

Output is as you expect it (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8NN0-ZO6tW)):

```
{
    "/api/endpoint1":"0.8s",
    "/api/endpoint2":"0.7s"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer icza, this solved the problem perfectly.